# mmap: mapping in user space a kernel buffer allocated with kmalloc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mmap

Which is the correct way to map in an user space process a buffer allocated with kmalloc? Maybe i didn't understand memory mapping yet...I write a kernel module that allocs this buffer (for example 120 bytes) and i would read and write it in a user-space process. Obviously i created a char device and implemented a `mmap` method in the `file_operations` struct. My method is:

```
static int my_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
  //printk(KERN_INFO "Allocated virtual memory length = %d", vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);

  long unsigned int size = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;

  if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start,
                      __pa(mem_area) >> PAGE_SHIFT,  //what about vma->vm_pgoff?
                      size,
                      vma->vm_page_prot) < 0)
    return -EAGAIN;

  vma->vm_flags |= VM_LOCKED;
  vma->vm_ops = &vmops;
  vma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;

  my_vm_open(vma);

  return 0;
}
```

where `mem_area` points at a memory area allocated with `kmalloc` at module init. The area is filled with the same value (for example 0x10). All works but i think there is something wrong in this code:

1. `kmalloc` could return a pointer that isn't page aligned and, in that case, i don't think is correct the value of the third parameter of `remap_pfn_range` in fact in user space i read the wrong value. Instead all works if i use `__get_free_page` (because the the function always returns a pointer that is page aligned) or when `kmalloc` returns a page aligned pointer. Memory mapping works with memory regions that are multple of `PAGE_SIZE` so, should i allocate an entire page instead of using `kmalloc`?
2. When `my_mmap` is called, the kernel has allocated some pages yet? I ask this because i found some implementations of custom `mmap` method that call `remap_pfn_range` with `vma->vm_pgoff` as third parameter...how could be useful this? Is this the page frame of the first new allocated page? If i pass as third parameter a page frame like i do in `my_mmap`, i should free pages starting from page in `vma->vm_pgoff`?
3. However i found an implementation of `mmap` method that maps a buffer allocated with `kmalloc`. To correctly map the buffer an operation (that i don't undestand for now) is performed before `remap_pfn_range`. Suppose that `mem` is the pointer returned by `kmalloc`, `mem_area` is initialized in this manner:

   ```
   mem_area=(int *)(((unsigned long)mem + PAGE_SIZE - 1) & PAGE_MASK);
   ```

So `mem_area` contains the same value of `mem` only if `mem` is page aligned otherwise is should contain the pointer at the beginning of the next page. However, with this operation if i pass as third param of `remap_pfn_range` the value `__pa(mem_area) >> PAGE_SHIFT` mapping works well. Why?

Thank you all!

Comment: I have a similar question but with using boot param `mmap`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12790382/143897 ? Could you provide some of your findings ? Thanks.

Comment: Don't you need a page fault handler here for the vm_operations_struct.fault ?

Comment: Minimal runnable example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760479/how-to-mmap-a-linux-kernel-buffer-to-user-space/45645732#45645732

Answer (score 6):

1. Yes, you should be allocating a whole number of pages.
2. No, the kernel hasn't allocated any pages.  `vm->vm_pgoff` is the requested offset within the device being mapped - it's the last parameter to the userspace `mmap()` call, translated from bytes to pages.  You're probably looking at the `mem` or `kmem` mmap implementations, in which case the offset represents the physical or linear page that userspace wants to map.
3. That is just allocating a page-aligned buffer within the `kmalloc()` allocated buffer.  You're better off using `__get_free_pages()` as you've already surmised, cutting out the middle-man.

You should be testing that the size being mapped does not exceed your buffer.

Comment: Thank you caf for the anwser! I still don't understand point number 2...i did't look at `mem` or `kmem` implementations but i found it in Linux device driver book...now i know that `vma->vm_pgoff` is the offset within the device being mapped but if i pass to `remap_pfn_range` as third parameter `vma->vm_pgoff`, which memory in the device i'm mapping?

Comment: @caf I have a similar question but with using boot param mmap: stackoverflow.com/q/12790382/143897 ? Could you provide some of your findings ? Thanks.